# Random link javascript to ignore current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar

When I click the 'Random' link on my navbar (bootstrap) it refers to Javascript code (below) taking me to a random page on my mock website.

However I would like to add a feature, so if I'm on, say `Link[2]=fed-rates.html`, when I press the 'Random' link on my navbar it always takes me away from the page I'm currently on (that is, it ignores Link[2]).

I'm wondering whether this is possible, would be great to get some ideas.

Javascript code:

```
function randomlinks(){
    var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*2)
    var links=new Array()
    links[0]="articles/how-to-trade-oil.html"
    links[1]="articles/usd-yen-gbp.html"
    links[2]="articles/fed-rates.html"

    window.location=links[myrandom]
}

// above is for all web pages

function randomlinksarticle(){
    var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*2)
    var links=new Array()
    links[0]="how-to-trade-oil.html"
    links[1]="usd-yen-gbp.html"
    links[2]="fed-rates.html"

    window.location=links[myrandom]
}

// above is so navbar link still works on the linked pages, with the way I have the folder directory setup
```

New code that comes up with "/undefined" page:

```
function randomlinksarticle(){
var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*2)
var links=new Array()
links[0]="how-to-trade-oil.html"
links[1]="usd-yen-gbp.html"
links[2]="fed-rates.html"

links.forEach(function(link, index) {
if (location.href.indexOf(link) !== -1) {
    links.splice(index, 1);
}});
window.location=links[myrandom]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
links.forEach(function(link, index) {
    if (location.href.indexOf(link) !== -1) {
        links.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

This looks through all the links and checks if they exist in the current URL. If they do, it removes them from the list using the splice function.

Add this code after setting link[2], since that's when it should be removing the current page.

---

Edit: I also noticed that your random function isn't evenly distributed. Not that it matters that much, but it could cause problems for you. The reason for this is that there are many more numbers between 0 and 2 that round to 1 than to 0 or two. In order to get a zero from your random number scale, Math.random() has to be less than 0.5. Likewise, it has to be greater than or equal to 1.5 to get a 2. you have a 0.5/2 or 1/4 probability for 0 and 2. This leaves a 1/2 probability for getting one, which makes sense since all numbers between 0.5 and 1.5 would give you a 1.

tl;dr: Use `math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum + 1))` rather than `Math.round(Math.random() * maximum)` for generating random numbers.

---

Also, if you want a less repetitive way to do this, you could substitute both functions for something like this:

```
function randomLink() {
    var links = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0); //Turns the function's arguments into an array
    links.forEach(function(link, index) { //Loops through all the links
        if (location.href.indexOf(link) !== -1) { //If the link text is contained in the url
            links.splice(index, 1); //Remove the link from the links array
        }
    });
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length); //Choose a number between 0 and links.length - 1
    window.location = links[rand]; //Visit the link
}
```

You could call this like `randomLink("first_page.html", "second_page.html")` with an arbitrary number of pages.

Comment: This is great, it prevents bringing up the same page when I click the link. However I occasionally get an error page and the URL is "/undefined".

Maybe this is because of where I placed the code?
(see bottom code box in my question)

Comment: You have to generate the random number afterwards using the function I described. If you're removing a link, the length of the link array isn't going always going to be 3. For example, ["link a", "link b", "link c"] may change to ["link b", "link c"]. Therefore, the random number generator should generate a number between 0 and links.length - 1. However, simply changing Math.random()*2 to Math.random() won't solve the issue since you can't be sure of the length of the array. Instead, you should use `Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length)` for myrandom and set it *after* the ForEach statement